# Pool connection in IIS

Tags: iis, concurrency, queue, connection, pool

I need to do the following, if possible, I need to configure a connection pool in IIS, the idea is that I want to have a limit of 20 concurrent connections, a queue of 10 concurrent connections and lets say that I get 35 concurrent connections, then the server will receive the first 20 connections, process them and the next 10 will be put in the queue and those will get processed according the other connections are finished and the remaining 5 will get the 503 message.
Is this possible? Is there an application that can help me achieve this?

Comment: "the remaining 5 will get the 503 message." This is impossible. IIS only returns 503 when application pool stops or crashes. Requests in the queue will only display blank pages and continuous loading prompts in the browser. When the loading time is too long, only timeout prompts will be received, not 503.

Comment: Ok, so checking for Connection Pooling, I found that basically what I need is to configure a reverse proxy so I can have this functionality.  For example Nginx or HAProxy that have this option.  I think that also IIS can be configure to do this so I will check that part.
If someone has information of doing this I will appreciate it.